# What are azeotropic mixtures?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I’m not able to get the qualitative idea of azeotropic mixture.

What does it mean in simple language?

Comment: Try google eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two components in a mixture, say water and ethanol, and you heat the liquid to the boiling point of that mixture (at the given pressure), you may find that the composition of the resulting vapor and the remaining liquid are different. In that case, you have a non-azeotropic mixture and the composition of vapor and liquid will change as you continue boiling.

For the case of water/ethanol, at some point, the composition of vapor and liquid will match (and no longer change, no matter how long you boil, until all liquid has evaporated). That composition/mixture is called an azeotrope.

The liquid mixture of oxygen/nitrogen is an example for a system that does not show an azeotrope.

Comment: After the composition of vapour and liquid matches why is there no change in composition no matter how long we boil?                              This is the point that I’m unable to grasp.

Comment: @RitwikDas My explanation to that takes us into the realm of statistics.

Comment: would love to hear it.